# How to implement less and greater than in C# generic container?

Tags: c#

In C++, with priority queue I can write:

```
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, greater<int>> min_pq;
priority_queue<int, vector<int>, less<int>> max_pq;
```

I wonder is there an equivalent way to do it in C# container? I'm implementing a priority queue, where I need a way to specify this behavior when the user use its constructor. I could use  a `boolean` flag, but it just doesn't look right to me. Any idea?

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> where T : IComparable<T> {
     private List<T> data;

     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
     /// <param name="item"></param>
     public void Push(T item) {

     }

     /// <summary>
     /// 
     /// </summary>
     public void Pop() {

     } 
}
```

Comment: I'm not understanding the question very well, but do you need something like a SortedList ?
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.sortedlist.aspx

Comment: Yes, similar but I want to specify the sorting criteria in the template argument instead of constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An idiomatic solution in C# is to pass an instance of [`IComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) to the constructor of your generic class.

```
public class PriorityQueue<T> {
    private readonly IComparer<T> comparer;
    public PriorityQueue(IComparer<T> comp = null) {
        comparer = comp ?? Comparer<T>.Default;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, so there is no way we can specify this behavior in template argument?

Comment: @Chan No, you cannot do it as a template argument, at least not as easily as in C++. The problem is, you'd need to create an interface, use it as a restriction, and then create an instance of your `greater_then` every time you want to compare two items. This is by far less efficient than with an instance of `IComparere<T>`.

Comment: You could have another template argument U, restricted to IComparer<T>, and you could create an instance of it in your constructor, but it will just look weird in C#.

Answer (score 2):

In the general sense, this can be achieved by referring to `int Comparer<T>.Default.Compare(T x, T y)`. This wraps a number of different implementation patterns, including:

- `IComparable` (non-generic)
- `IComparable<T>` (generic)

  - and handling "lifted" operation via `Nullable<T>`

this is basically how `List<T>` applies `Sort()`, etc.

However! There is no direct way of applying, say, the `<` / `>` **operators** via a restriction; operators don't really work with generics - it is not the same as C++ templates.

Another approach would be to use `dynamic`. Because this is inspected per-type, rather than "for all T", in generics, this allows `dynamic` to use operators; but it requires boxing of value-types, and a bit of indirection.